# Helmet errors with renderStatic

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-helmet

I'm trying to setup Helmet npm using SSR within my meteor application and I'm getting the error, `Error running template: TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderStatic' of undefined at sink`. I'm new to using SSR so I'm not following what I'm missing here. Very nooooob question.

Path: `server/main.js`

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { onPageLoad } from "meteor/server-render";
import { renderToNodeStream } from "react-dom/server";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components"
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';  

import App from "/imports/server/app/App";

onPageLoad(sink => {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const appJSX = sheet.collectStyles(
    <App location={sink.request.url} />
  );

  App.propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object,
  };


  const htmlStream = sheet.interleaveWithNodeStream(
    renderToNodeStream(appJSX)
    );

  sink.renderIntoElementById("react-root-app", htmlStream);

  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  sink.appendToHead(helmet.meta.toString());
  sink.appendToHead(helmet.title.toString());

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Helmet is default export you need to import it like

```
  import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
```

But not

```
  import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
```

Comment: Ok, that's removed the error, but the metadata isn't appearing on the page. See update

Comment: Ok if this issue is resolved I would request you to put that as a separate question so that it will help future readers

Answer (score 0):

However, the latest version does not have a default import.

You must import it like this.

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
```

This is as per the version

```
"react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
```